# Hard drive has only one Ubuntu partition, how do I install Windows to dual-boot?

Tags: partitioning, windows, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Windows 7 after I’ve installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

I'm using 12.04 64-bit on my ThinkPad R61i with an un-partitioned 160GB hard drive. Can I partition my hard drive and install Windows for dual boot without having to reformat my laptop?

If yes, how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean Windows 7.

Boot from a LiveCd/USB and use gparted to shrink your one partition and make space for Windows. Then install Windows to that space. Windows will overwrite grub so boot from LiveCD again, and reinstall grub, running sudo update-grub.

Answer (score 1):

boot for a live disk or a other bootable disk and use a partiting tool to parition your hard disk drive(hdd) or solid sate drive (ssd).